# Acceptance testing MVC4 website with SpecFlow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I want to write acceptance tests, with SpecFlow (Gherkin) to verify different scenarios. Especially I want to verify the login process, that uses persistant cookies and sessionstate.

I've done something similar with services, where I programmatically started each service needed for the test, in a servicehost. This enables me to manipulate the IoC container before the service is instantiated.

I want something similar for my MVC controllers. Does anyone have any experience with this sort of testing in MVC 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html)

Here is an example with [Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests.UI
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestGoogleSearch
    {
        IWebDriver _driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
                                       //path to chrome driver exe
            _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\MyProject\lib\");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            _driver.Quit();
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSearchGoogleForTheAutomatedTester()
        {          
            //Given

            //When
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            IWebElement queryBox = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            queryBox.SendKeys("stack overflow");
            queryBox.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown);
            queryBox.Submit();

            //Then
            Assert.True(_driver.Title.Contains("stack overflow"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I don't see any server in your setup, and no way to manipulate the IoC container. I need to control the server and the way it initializes the mvc website. And I need to dp this from a C# method (testmethod).